# Автоматическая корректировка ширины Label под Content

Tags: c#, wpf

На форме в определенном месте есть Label, которая показывает уведомления. Текст уведомления может быть разной длины. Поэтому надо корректировать ширину Label под длину текста.

Схема:
[image: Схема]

Comment: Вы должны воспользоваться Layout Manager'ом, и не давать явное ограничение на ширину. В большинстве случаев ширина вырастет сама как надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример верстки по указанной в вопросе схеме (Независимо от размера текста уведомление будет находиться снизу и по центру, но при этом над DataGrid):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Колонка 1"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Колонка 2"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Колонка 3"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Колонка 4"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Border Margin="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Foreground="Red" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Тут находиться ваше уведомление с очень, ну прям очень, длинным текстом"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Так выглядит разметка при таком XAML коде:
[image: Так выглядит разметка при таком XAML коде]

**Дополнительно**

[Очень хороший сайт "professorweb.ru"](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/base_WPF/level1/base_WPF_index.php) с довольно понятным описанием работы с XAML и вообще WPF. Очень рекомендую почитать про верстку.